# Return object instance with current state

Tags: php, this, instance, clone

Are there any differences between

```
$this->state = $state;
return $this;
```

and

```
$instance = clone $this;
$instance->state = $state;
return $instance;
```

Context:

```
class TestCase {

    /**
     * State
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * Set state
     */
    function setState($state) {
        $this->state = $state;
        return $this;
        // Or
        // $instance = clone $this;
        // $instance->state = $state;
        // return $instance;
    }

}
$test = new TestCase;
$test->setState($state1)->setState($state2);
```

Comment: what do you mean difference, one is $this the other is a clone of $this.  Clone is like copy, it's a duplicate.   If you mean is the value the same, well that is what a copy is a duplicate, if you copy a file and rename it is the contents the same...  Yes, until they diverge.  Now if you check this `spl_object_hash` they are not the same.

Comment: The only difference in your example, would be in the second one if you never apply state to the original this and only to the clone, then obviously they have diverged.  It's like coping the file, then editing the copied file without changing the original.  They become 2 separate distinct entities when cloned.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I have just added the context I'm in. Thanks for your quick replies.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the clone, the reason is that you lose the 'state' because you are basically lying and not changing the original object, which could result in unexpected values later.  Imagine adding a method `getState`, well the state of what object.  It's unnecessarily complicating things, and negatively affects readability of the code.  That said in this case the value would be the same but later on down the road you would be using `$test` not the clone of it.

Comment: In short it's pointless because you are not storing the clone, so there is no way to maintain that state outside of the call to set it, which means you might as well just use the original local variable you fed the method to begin with.  Because you are not preserving the state of the clone.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Thanks for your advices. I see many people using `clone` in this case and don't know why they do it. I just want to return object instance with current state, so I will keep using `return $this` method :)

Comment: I almost never use clone, I could see using it in a factory type method where you need to create several objects with initial values or states that are the same.  But in that case I wouldn't call it `setState`, as `set` anything implies you are setting something on that instance.  They may have valid reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS an example if you do this

```
 $test = new TestCase;
 $test->setState(1)->setState(2);

 $test->getState();
```

Then what clone are you using, the answer is none, because `$test` is the original object which has never actually had it's state set.  The other 2 clones are discarded at the end of the method chain.

The method chain may return the correct value, but if you take the obect `$test` into a different scope, such as

```
function a(){
      $this->test = new TestCase;
      $this->test->setState(1)->setState(2);
}

function b(){
    echo $this->test->setState(3);
}
```

Then test has never known about the other 2 states, as I said it's some what pointless.

Typically you would want to clone an object if you were forking it after setting some initial value.  An example would be like a query builder, where you build the query and then clone it to do a separate query to count the results ( minus a limit or order for example )

```
 $Qb = new QueryBuilder();
 $Qb->select('*')->table('posts')->where( 'published', '<', '2014-02-20' );

  //copy and diverge to count results,
 $tQb = clone $Qb;
 $tQb->select('COUNT(id) AS total');  
 $total = $tQb->getResult();

  // add limits to original instance.
 $Qb->limit('20');
 $rows = $Qb->getResult();
```

See cloning would be used to save setting up the initial part of the query, then you copy and diverge them for the individual needs.  One to count the total results one to pull a limited number of results.  Which is useful if you had several joins and multiple parts to the where clause etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken two different object's are produced when you clone.

Comment: I wouldn't say different, as the clone is the copy so it's the same object with the same state as the original but a separate instance from that point on.

Comment: Thank you! No, I just want to return only one current object instance with current state.